# Python 3 cannot zip a folder and move it to another folder

Tags: python

I m currently using the shutil library to zip the file,

```
Current folder structure
```

*In the d drive*

**A_zipdirectory.py** for running the python code

**A_dest** folder to be zipped

**A_backup** folder that will stored the zipped folder

> Python code

```
import shutil

import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)

zip_loc = 'D:/A_dest'
zip_dest = 'D:/A_backup'
shutil.make_archive(base_dir=zip_loc, root_dir=zip_loc, format='zip', 
base_name=zip_dest)
```

When i run this, No error occurs, but i cannot zip and move the file to the backup folder, Any idea? Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your folder path is correct? If you use an absolute path, maybe your file(or dir) path should prefix with driver letter.(e.g. D:/A_dest)

Comment: Have tried to use  D:/A_dest with no luck, just starting to learn this

Comment: As my comment says you should change your path on Windows. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add logger and see what happening. (you can deliver logger to shutil.make_archive)

sorry it answer and not comment, i can't comment yet

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'A_dest'

Comment: where do you run the script from?

Comment: try to use absolute path instead of relative

Comment: ? care to explain further

Comment: in your case:
r"d:\A_backup".

relative path is partial, and absolute is full path. it like telling the python look for the file here, or look for the file in (36.395121, 17.346487)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180996/discussion-between-socketplayer-and-epiphany).